# Break if element of an object in watch has specific value

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I have added a element to my watchlist. Is it possible to set a breakpoint if the value of a element matches a specific value?

[image]

E.g. it should stop as soons as the value of the element `className` is `mceEditor`.
At the moment I have to manually go to this position step by step by step...

Is this possible? Are there any developer tools which are capable of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that there are conditional breakpoints.
I added one at the correct spot and now it is just like I desired.

[image: elm.className == 'mceEditor']

**Chrome**: Open the developer tools and open the tab "sources". then right click on the line number and select "**Add conditional breakpoint**" and set your condition.